# References on state space models and time series

Tags: r, time-series, references, state-space-models

I would like to study time series modeling and state space modeling for the purpose of modeling a complex physical system (vibrations of an industrial machine). The system is mostly linear (small deformation hypothesis applies), but there could be nonlinearities due to coupling with the operating fluid. I had a look at the available books, but there's a huge number of them and I don't know how to choose. Can you point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**: I'm mostly interested in state estimation and model calibration, however also more generic references may be of help, because I'm relatively new to the field.

Comment: @RichardHardy, thanks for the edit, I didn't know there was a `reference` tag, and it's pretty popular too! Nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have extensive experience in this area, but for an entry into the field I found the introductory materials by Sebastian Thrun to be accessible.

An overview of state-space modeling approaches is given in the earlier parts of the textbook

> Thrun, S., Burgard, W., & Fox, D. (2005). [Probabilistic robotics](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=14888597886920135272). MIT press.

which also has a [website](http://probabilistic-robotics.org/) with supplementary materials. An applied overview of this material is also contained in his Udacity course
[Artificial Intelligence for Robotics: Programming a Robotic Car](https://www.udacity.com/course/artificial-intelligence-for-robotics--cs373), which includes Python code, and is free (at the time of this writing).

For the classical linear-Gaussian case ([Kalman filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter)), I have mostly learned from online sources as needed. After you have some familiarity with the basics you might try a Google scholar search for papers in your *particular* application area, and then backtrack their "methods" references.

(Note also that the [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kalman-filters) and/or [Robotics](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kalman-filter) StackExchange sites might have more users with relevant experience, compared to here.)

Hope this helps!